# water relief valves on water heater

Tags: water-heater

I have an A.O.Smith water heater. The water heater in my garage has a outlet marked "relief valve" on the side of the water heater near the top, but nothing is connected to it. Instead the water relief valve is connected at the top of the water heater. Why is it so? Now  I am seeing occasional water dripping from the "relief valve" outlet. Is that a problem?

Comment: the relief valve is not leaking. The water comes from the outlet marked "relief valve", which did not have a valve installed. Is this simply the case of incorrect installation?

Comment: I'm not understanding from the description - can you post a photo?

Comment: Nothing is connected to the relief valve on the side of the heater, yet the water relief valve is connected at the top of the heater? I'm very confused! Clear, focused pictures would help greatly. Also, including the actual model number of the heater would help - it would allow someone to look up the documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

A dripping relief valve is a problem. Causes include: a failed valve, a faulty thermostat causing overheating, excessive water pressure, or water hammer causing overpressure.